# How to write a repeat element to each row in scrapy

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I am testing my hand at scraping with scrapy. Thrilled with progress so far, I have an issue where the data model of the source website doesn't seem to align with my current scrapy output.

Source provides Categories, Type, and URL data - each category contains multiple types, and each type has a URL.

I am looking to get an output maintaining the nesting of the data where each row associates the category, type, and URL grouping.

Both XLM and CSV outputs provide unique categories but hold all subsequent type and url data in columns for each category row.

Source/example site:

```html
<div class="box">
     <div class="coin-img coin-imgfile--9999 coin-img-3"></div>
     <div class="coin-heading">
     <h3>Half-Cents and Cents</h3>
</div>
<ul>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/liberty-cap-half-cent-1793-1797/34">Liberty Cap Half Cent (1793-1797)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/draped-bust-half-cent-1800-1808/653">Draped Bust Half Cent (1800-1808)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/classic-head-half-cent-1809-1836/654">Classic Head Half Cent (1809-1836)</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <div class="coin-img coin-imgfile--9999 coin-img-5"></div>
     <div class="coin-heading">
     <h3>Two and Three Cents</h3>
</div>
<ul>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/two-cent-1864-1873/670">Two Cent (1864-1873)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/three-cent-silver-1851-1873/77">Three Cent Silver (1851-1873)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/auctionprices/category/three-cent-nickel-1865-1889/671">Three Cent Nickel (1865-1889)</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Working spider scraping all necessary data, but not formatted as needed:

```py
import scrapy

class PCGSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pcgs_spider"
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml',
        'FEED_URI': 'pcgsspider.xml'
    }
    start_urls = ['abovesample.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.box'
        for pcgs in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            CAT_SELECTOR = 'h3 ::text'
            TYPE_SELECTOR = './/ul/li/a/text()'
            URL_SELECTOR = './/ul/li/a/@href'
            yield {
                    'categories': pcgs.css(CAT_SELECTOR).extract(),
                    'types': pcgs.xpath(TYPE_SELECTOR).extract(),
                    'type_url': pcgs.xpath(URL_SELECTOR).extract(),
            }
```

And the XML showing the right data, but not nested with each URL with its TYPE, and TYPE with its CATEGORY

```xml
-<item>
-<categories>
    <value>Half-Cents and Cents</value>
</categories>
-<types>
    <value>Liberty Cap Half Cent (1793-1797)</value>
    <value>Draped Bust Half Cent (1800-1808)</value>
    <value>Classic Head Half Cent (1809-1836)</value>
</types>
-<type_url>
    <value>/auctionprices/category/lincoln-cent-wheat-reverse-1909-1958/46</value>
    <value>/auctionprices/category/lincoln-cent-modern-1959-date/47</value>
    <value>/auctionprices/category/lincoln-cent-modern-1959-date/47</value>
</type_url>
</item>
```

Very new to this all so pardon any ignorance - it seems some level of iteration would resolve the problem, though it isn't clear to me if within my spider is the best place to resolve as the data and core of the structure is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to duplicate `CATEGORY` value for each link with type and url:

```
import scrapy

class PCGSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pcgs_spider"
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml',
        'FEED_URI': 'pcgsspider.xml'
    }
    start_urls = ['abovesample.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for div_box in response.css("div.box"):
            category = div_box.css("h3 ::text").extract_first()
            for li in div_box.css("ul li"):
                yield { 'category':category,
                        'type':li.css("a ::text").extract_first(),
                        'url' :li.css("a ::attr(href)").extract_first
                      }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm - though I need to work on the url extract. Getting some noise there

```csv
<bound method SelectorList.get of [<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::a/descendant-or-self::*/@href' data='/auctionprices/category/liberty-seated-h'>]>
```

Comment: I forgot to write `()` after last `.extract_first` method call

Answer (score 0):

You have to use extract_first() method instead of extract() on the categories field.Sample of what I got from scraping PCGS:

```
<items>
<item><categories>Half-Cents and Cents</categories><types>Liberty Cap Half Cent (1793-1797)</types><type_url>/auctionprices/category/liberty-cap-half-cent-1793-1797/34</type_url></item>
<item><categories>Two and Three Cents</categories><types>Two Cent (1864-1873)</types><type_url>/auctionprices/category/two-cent-1864-1873/670</type_url></item>
<item><categories>Nickels</categories><types>Shield Nickel (1866-1883)</types><type_url>/auctionprices/category/shield-nickel-1866-1883/81</type_url></item>
</items>
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I've played around a bit with extract_first(), I think with most promise only on CATEGORIES. In your result, does it continue and replicate for hundreds of rows with distinct combos of CATEGORIES + VALUES + URL in each?

When I use extract_first() on all, I get 15 rows, but just with the first TYPE and URL combo, not anything subsequent within a CATEGORY. extract_first() on just CATEGORY provides the same result as the original code.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, I can't help any further; at least for now.